# How to check channel state from MAC layer

Tags: omnet++, inet

In Omnet++ 5.5.1 with INET 4 framework, from MAC layer, I am trying to check if the physical channel is idle.
Would anyone please suggest me the code for that?

**UPDATE**
I'm using the following interface.

```
# wireless interface
**.wlan[*].typename = "WirelessInterface"
**.wlan[*].radio.typename = "ApskScalarRadio"
```

Thanking you.

Comment: What kind of physical channel? Ethernet? 802.11? 802.15.4? This is an implementation specific detail. Each physical medium is modeled differently, so this question cannot be (usefully) answered in general.

Comment: @Rudi, I have now updated my question. Would you please answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually radios implement the `IRadio` interface, and the medium state can be queried through various methods on that interface. Check the `CsmaCaMac.cc` file for examples. Here is the actual implementation you are looking for:

https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/linklayer/csmaca/CsmaCaMac.cc#L593